# Linux login with username pre-entered

Tags: linux, authentication

Is it pssible to have your username pre-entered when logging in to your local Linux box using util-linux login (not a login manager). So that you could just hit Enter and have a password prompt, or use backspace to delete the name and type in another one if necessary?

I log in with the same username almost all the time - so that would be a time saver.